# Oracle Insert de várias linhas

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer o insert de vários registros em uma tabela onde apenas um deles mudará, os outros são constantes.

Por exemplo:

```
Insert into processo (ID, status, descricao) values (1, 'X01', 'lorem ipsum dolor')
```

Tenho que fazer centenas de inserts como esse acima, onde o status e a descrição será sempre o mesmo mas para ID's diferentes.

Da pra fazer isso com um único insert ou preciso criar uma função? Como?

Comment: qual a versão do oracle?

Comment: @MarllonNasser 11g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o `INSERT ALL`:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO processo (id, status, descricao) VALUES (1, 'X01', 'lorem ipsum dolor')
  INTO processo (id, status, descricao) VALUES (2, 'X02', 'lorem ipsum dolor2')
  INTO processo (id, status, descricao) VALUES (3, 'X03', 'lorem ipsum dolor3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Você também pode fazer insert em outras tabelas se quiser :)

Comment: Essa é a unica forma com insert? Vou precisar de centenas de linhas mudando o ID apenas.

Comment: Com insert sim, amigo..... A outra forma seria através de pl/sql.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer apenas fazer um incremento no ID de 1 em 1, pode fazer uma Stored Procedure(conjunto de comandos) com um while e o insert.
Como Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tbCliente(
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 numero int,
 nome varchar(50),
 PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT default 1;
WHILE i<=100 DO
    INSERT INTO tbCliente(nome,numero) values ('Nomes',i);
    SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
call myProc();
```

Com esse código será incrementado de 1 em 1 o valor i em cada insert de 1 até 100, onde 'i' faz referência ao campo 'numero' da tabela tbCliente.
O DELIMITER onde diz para o sql, onde o código da procedure inicia e termina.
call muProc() executará sua procedure, depois é apenas necessário fazer o select para ver se tudo deu certo.

Lembre de executar o DELIMITER$$ junto com a procedure e depois o DELIMITER; junto com o call myproc().

Comment: Na verdade não é sequencial. As IDs são de outra consulta e precisava dar um insert em outra tabela que tem esse ID como FK.
Sei que é possível com PL/SQL, mas como não domino acabei conectando com uma aplicação só pra criar uma função pra fazer isso.